# How should we do when encounter a tree only contains a label in Random Forest?

Tags: random-forest, decision-tree

when using random forest to create trees, I found there"s a tree contains with only a label, and has no other nodes, looks like that: Tree: {yes}. It leeads to error when I use my forest to predict .
I would like to know what's the commen solution for this probelem.
is it to add a judge function that when the tree only contains a lable, create a new tree ;
or in I need to modify the createTree function.

here is my full code in github:
https://github.com/suchunxie/Random_forest_sample.git

Thank you if you can nicely give some syggestion.

Comment: A  interesting hyperparameter is the `maximum depth of decision trees` used in the ensemble.By default, trees are constructed to an arbitrary depth and are not pruned. This is a sensible default, although we can also explore fitting trees with different fixed depths.The maximum tree depth can be specified via the `max_depth` argument